# Unable to get Angular-Route working

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, cordova, angular-routing

Im trying to make use of the templates and routing with AngularJS and i believe i have it set up properly though it will not work. I have looked through stack overflow as well as different forums online and non of the recommended solutions have worked for me at all.

My AngularModule looks like:

```
var app = angular.module('Contacts',['ngRoute']);

app.controller('main', function($scope){
$scope.visible = false;
$scope.contacts = [];

//add object to array
$scope.newContact = function(){
    $scope.contacts.push({name:$scope.ContactName, phone:$scope.ContactPhone, email:$scope.ContactEmail});

    $scope.ContactName = '';
    $scope.ContactPhone = '';
    $scope.ContactEmail = '';
};

$scope.remove = function(item) {
    var index = $scope.contacts.indexOf(item)
    $scope.contacts.splice(index,1);
}

app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when('/',{
        templateURL : 'pages/home.html',
        controller : 'main'
    })
    .when('/add', {
        templateURL : 'pages/add.html',
        controller : 'addController'
    })
    .when('/details',{
        templateURL : 'pages/details.html',
        controller : 'detailsController'
    });

});


app.controller('addController', function($scope) {
});

app.controller('detailsController', function($scope) {
});
});
```

This seems to be set up properly though my below HTML still stays blank:

```
<html ng-app="Contacts" class="ng-scope">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
    <!-- WARNING: for iOS 7, remove the width=device-width and height=device-height attributes. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4323 -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"/>
    <title>Contracts</title>
</head>
<body ng-controller= "main">
        <h1>Contacts</h1>
        <div ng-view></div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/node_modules/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/node_modules/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/ContactsModule.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        app.initialize();
    </script>
</body>
```

Also my file structure is very simple:

```
/
/pages
/pages/home.html
/pages/add.html
/pages/details.html
```

Is there something i am missing?  This has completely escaped me and i have spent a lot of time trying to figure this one out.
Also i am testing on localhost.

Comment: Order of script loading is not correct. Load angular.js and associated scripts first and ContactsModule.js, index.js next. Try this

Comment: i just tried that, didnt work

Comment: this may be a moot point, but you do close your `<html>` tag after the `<body>` tag, right?

Comment: @ShehryarAbbasi I do, i just forgot to add that when i copied it

Comment: Your app.config should not be inside your controller. You forgot to close your controller before starting your app.config

Comment: okay, figured as much, so what do you see in your dev tools (in Chrome for example) - any errors in the Console, Network, Sources tabs? also, what does `/pages/home.html`  contain? ..AND @trevor has a good point !

Comment: @trevor im trying that now

Comment: @trevor i can see the URL changing now, i am just not seeing my html from home.html

Comment: Also remove ng-controller= "main" from your html body element. It is declared in your config. No need to have it in your html.

Comment: @trevor i have tried all of these things and its still not working

Comment: @trevor my address bar states "index.html#/ " then doesnt show anything

Comment: In your config function, change each occurrence of 'templateURL' to 'templateUrl'

Comment: @trevor i tried that and still nothing. My Url looks like this when it loads "www/index.html#/"

Comment: can you check your console for errors.

Comment: I did i have no error, just got this one though

Comment: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome-extension, https

Answer (score 0):

You could try $stateProvider insted of $routeProvider

```
 $stateProvider
    .state('home', {
        url: '/home',
        templateUrl: 'Entities/Home.html',            
    })
    .state('company', {
        url: '/company',
        templateUrl: 'Entities/Company.html',
        controller: 'CompanyController'
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, our conversation in the comments above was getting a bit long, so here's my answer for you.

The following is a stripped-down version of your html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="Contacts">
<head>    
  <title>Contacts</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Contacts</h1>
  <div ng-view></div>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.15/angular-route.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Notice that I have included index.js (which I assume is the js code you posted) after I have included angular.min.js and angular-route.min.js. Nevermind that I am getting them from a CDN (content delivery network), your links should work just fine assuming that you installed angular with node (by typing 'npm install angular' at the command line)...but I do question why you have your node_modules folder inside a 'js' folder. Are you using node and npm or not???

I am using the html above with your index.js file, which I have organized like this:

```
var app = angular.module('Contacts',['ngRoute']);

app.controller('main', function($scope){
  $scope.visible = false;
  $scope.contacts = [];

  //add object to array
  $scope.newContact = function(){
    $scope.contacts.push({name:$scope.ContactName, phone:$scope.ContactPhone, email:$scope.ContactEmail});

    $scope.ContactName = '';
    $scope.ContactPhone = '';
    $scope.ContactEmail = '';
  };

  $scope.remove = function(item) {
    var index = $scope.contacts.indexOf(item);
    $scope.contacts.splice(index,1);
  };

});

app.controller('addController', function($scope) {
});

app.controller('detailsController', function($scope) {
});

app.config(function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when('/',{
      templateUrl : 'pages/home.html',
      controller : 'main'
    })
    .when('/add', {
      templateUrl : 'pages/add.html',
      controller : 'addController'
    })
    .when('/details',{
      templateUrl : 'pages/details.html',
      controller : 'detailsController'
    });
});
```

And I have three html files like you do: pages/home.html, pages/add.html, and pages/details.html. Each file contains only a single div tag with the name of the destination like: `<div>Home</div>`

My project folder structure is:

```
my_project
 - js
    - index.js
 - pages
    - add.html
    - details.html
    - home.html
 index.html
```

This code is working properly on my machine and should also work on yours. In order for it to work, you must be running the code on a web server. So you must either have hosting from a company somewhere, or be running a program like [MAMP (for Mac OS)](https://www.mamp.info/en/), [WAMP (Windows)](http://www.wampserver.com/en/), or [XAMPP (Mac OS OR Windows)](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html).